# show that for $\mathcal F$ $\sigma$- field to be countably generated there is some $X$ random variable s.t. $\mathcal F=\sigma(X)$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Show that a necessary and sufficient condition for $\mathcal F$ $\sigma$- field to be countably generated is that for some $X$ random variable  $\mathcal F=\sigma(X)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proof of Sufficiency** Set $A_q := \{X \leq q\}$, where $q\in\mathbb{Q}$. It is easy to check $$\mathcal{F} = \sigma(X) = \sigma(A_q:q\in\mathbb{Q}).$$

**Proof of Necessity** Suppose $\mathcal{F} = \sigma(A_n : n\in\mathbb{N})$. Set $$X := \sum_n 3^{-n}1_{A_n}.$$ Clearly, $X$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable, and so $\mathcal{F}\supset \sigma(X)$. Moreover, observe that $$\bigcup\left\{S + 3^{-n}/2 < X \leq S + 3^{-n} : S \in \left\{\sum_{i < n}\epsilon_i3^{-i}:\epsilon_i = 0\text{ or }1\right\}\right\} = A_n$$ and so $\mathcal{F}\subset \sigma(X)$.