# Countably Generated Sigma field

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

I need to show that a sigma field $\mathcal{G}$ is countably generated if and only if there exists a random variable $X$ such that $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(X)$.

For the sufficiency part, I would say $\mathcal{G}=\{X^{-1}(B): B\in \mathcal{R}\}=\sigma(\{\omega:X(\omega)\leq x\}: x\in\mathbb{R})=\sigma(\{\omega:X(\omega)<a\}: a\in\mathbb{Q})$ which is countably generated.

For necessity part I have the following hint: If $\mathcal{G}=\sigma(A_1,A_2,\cdots)$, consider $X=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{f(I_{A_k})}{10^K}$, where $f(x)=\begin{cases}4\;\;\text{if }x=0\\5\;\;\text{if }x\neq 0\end{cases}$.

Thus, I need to show that for this construction of X, $\sigma(X)=\sigma(A_1,A_2,\cdots)$. Any thoughts?

Comment: It is clear that $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable (this follows from a general theorem for limit of measurable functions), hence $\sigma(X)\subset\mathcal{G}$. To prove that $\mathcal{G}\subset\sigma(X)$, it would be sufficient to express the sets $A_i$ in terms of $X$. For example, one has $A_1=\{X\geq 5/10\}$...

Comment: Any progress on this question?

Comment: [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1216201/36150)